# How can I get the correct position of a tkinter canvas after scrolling down using scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, tkinter-canvas

I'm making paint in Python using `customtkinter`. I have a scrollable canvas and when I click on canvas it draws an oval using cursor position. But when I'm scrolling down and trying to draw something, it draws everything not in the right position.

Here's my code:

```
from customtkinter import *
from tkinter import Scrollbar

set_appearance_mode('System')
set_default_color_theme('dark-blue')

window = CTk()  # Window
window.geometry("800x520")

fill_color = '#000000'

def draw_with_brush(event):
    fx, fy = event.x - 1 , event.y - 1
    lx, ly = fx + 1, fy + 1
    canvas.create_oval((fx, fy, lx, ly), outline=fill_color, width=10, fill=fill_color)

canvas = CTkCanvas(window, bg='white', bd=2, relief=SUNKEN, height=430, width=700, scrollregion=(0,0,100000,100000))
canvas.place(x=60, y=50)
canvas.bind("<B1-Motion>", draw_with_brush)

x_scroll = Scrollbar(window, orient=HORIZONTAL, command=canvas.xview)
x_scroll.place(x=60, y=495, width=700)
y_scroll = Scrollbar(window, orient=VERTICAL, command=canvas.yview)
y_scroll.place(x=780, y=50, height=430)

canvas.config(xscrollcommand=x_scroll.set, yscrollcommand=y_scroll.set)

window.mainloop()  # Loop
```

I understand that I have this problem because I'm scrolling down and this don't make any changes to my position where oval will be. But I don't know any method which will say me how position of canvas changed after I scrolled down.

I tried using functions `Canvas.canvasx()` and `Canvas.canvasy()` but I got exactly the same result.

Comment: You need to use `Canvas.canvasx()` and `Canvas.canvasy()` to convert the event coordinates to canvas coordinates.

Comment: That didn't work

Comment: *"That didn't work"* means nothing to us. It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Without a [mre], we cannot identify the cause of your issue.

Comment: I added my code to this question

Comment: If the line `fx, fy = event.x - 1 , event.y - 1` is changed to `fx, fy = canvas.canvasx(event.x) - 1 , canvas.canvasy(event.y) - 1`, it works.

Comment: Oh, it actually works. Thanks! Now it's a question dublicate. Should I delete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canvas has methods named `canvasx` and `canvasy` which will convert window coordinates to canvas coordinates.

Your drawing function should look like this:

```
def draw_with_brush(event):
    x = event.widget.canvasx(event.x)
    y = event.widget.canvasy(event.y)
    fx, fy = x - 1 , y - 1
    lx, ly = fx + 1, fy + 1
    event.widget.create_oval((fx, fy, lx, ly), outline=fill_color, width=10, fill=fill_color)
```

Comment: For consistency, `event.widget.create_oval(...)` should be used instead.